# Size of the "fixed" terms in the prime k-tuple conjecture

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The prime $k$-tuple conjecture predicts that for $(a_{1}n + b_{1}), \ldots, (a_{k}n + b_{k})$ an "admissible" k-tuple, where the $a_{i}, b_{i}$'s are fixed, then there are 
$$ \sim c \frac{x}{(\log{x})^{k}} $$ integers $n \leq x$ such that all $a_{i}n + b_{i}$ are simultaneously prime.

I cannot find any mention of the $a_{i},b_{i}$'s varying however.  That is, what happens (or is expected to happen) when these grow as a function of $x$ as well, say as some small power of $x$?  Is there some conjecture, or preliminary results?  Essentially I'm wondering if somehow implied by the conjecture or by other work is the fact that if the conjecture holds as stated above then it holds whenever $a_{i}, b_{i} \leq f(x)$ for f some function.

Comment: I think what's happening here is that your $c$ depends on the $a_i$ and $b_i$ in a somewhat complicated way that people don't often write down. For example, for the forms $n,n+2$, the relevant $c$ is called "the twin prime constant", you'll find a formula for it by searching that phrase.

Comment: Yes I think that's true. What I'm "concerned" about is if the $a_{i}, b_{i}$ becoming very large affects the result.  Roughly speaking, for fixed $a_{i}, b_{i}$ we can find an $x$ such that for looking at all $n \leq x$ we get arbitrarily close to the asymptotic.  However, if now the $a_{i}$'s are taken to be *of the size of this x* then how close to the asymptotic are we now?  I believe I've found a result which implies that the length of the interval you have to look in for $n$ is essentially independent of the $a_{i}, b_{i}$'s, but it's hard to be sure and feels kind of unintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

A plausible formula is given by the [Bateman-Horn conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture).